# style not recognized when placed in the head tag

Tags: javascript, css, styles

The following code works only if I remove the style for h1 from the head tag and use inline style as shown in the commented line, but does not work as listed below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1 {
                text-align: center; 
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function changeColor()
            {
                var dom = document.getElementById("head1"); 
                var clr = dom.style.color;
                switch(clr)
                {
                    case 'black':
                        dom.style.color = "red";
                        break;
                    case 'red':
                        dom.style.color = "black";
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onclick="changeColor()">
        <!-- <h1 id="head1" style="text-align: center; color: black;">CLICK ON ME!</h1> -->
        <h1 id="head1">CLICK ON ME!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: You won't find style properties declared via CSS on DOM element "style" objects. They're implied, but not directly visible like your code expects them to be.

Comment: Toggle a class instead of trying to manipulate the element style directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read a style off an element that comes from a stylesheet, you have to use the computed style which you can obtain with [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Styles applied via stylesheeets are not readable via `elem.style`.  That only shows styles that are directly applied to that specific element (not inherited from stylesheets or parents).

You could change your code like this and then it would work with the style sheet values in addition to directly applied values:

```
        function changeColor()
        {
            var dom = document.getElementById("head1"); 
            var clr = getComputedStyle(dom, null).getPropertyValue("color");
            switch(clr)
            {
                case 'black':
                    dom.style.color = "red";
                    break;
                case 'red':
                    dom.style.color = "black";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Note: `getComputedStyle()` requires IE9 or higher.  IE8 and earlier had a different way of doing the same thing so when supporting older versions of IE, a polyfill of some sort such as is shown [here](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/) is necessary.

---

FYI, for your particular objective here, it is probably a better design pattern to just toggle a class on/off on the element and leave all the styling to the the CSS based on whether the class name is present or not and not put specific style parameters in your Javascript.

Comment: The following code: var clr = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null).getPropertyValue("color"); returns rgb(0,0,0) instead of 'black' or 'red' which fails. Do you know why?

Comment: @user2340048 - I don't know why, but I do know that it can vary from system to system since there are multiple ways (at least three) to specify the same color.   This is even more reason to change a class name rather than a style value because you won't have this problem testing for a class name.

Answer (score -1):

The default value for an inline attr is "" which is a falsy value. Therefore you need a default value.

```
switch(clr) {
    case 'black':
        dom.style.color = "red";
        break;
    case 'red':
        dom.style.color = "black";
        break;
    default:
        dom.style.color = "red";

}
```

or it could be cleaner if you do it by adding and removing classes to avoid specificity of style attr that has 1000 of value